# Change the name of many files at the same time

Tags: command-line

I want to change the name files `cv.aux`, `cv.log` and `cv.out` for `Official_Curriculum_Vitae.aux`, `Official_Curriculum_Vitae.log` and `Official_Curriculum_Vitae.out` in only one simple command. Is there such a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mmv` is such a command (available to install from the `universe` repository).

```
NAME
       mmv - move/copy/append/link multiple files by wildcard patterns
```

e.g. in your case

```
mmv 'cv.*' 'Official_Curriculum_Vitae.#1'
```

Otherwise, either

```
prename -v -- 's/^cv/Official_Curriculum_Vitae/' cv.*
```

or regular `mv` with a simple shell loop

```
for f in cv.*; do mv -v -- "$f" "Official_Curriculum_Vitae.${f#cv.}"; done
```